# How to display a value in input text field?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I am using a select tag which has several options, when I select one option it should display a certain value that I have to manually set in the input field below.

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo-100</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab-200</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-300</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi-400</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

So for example if I select Volvo the input field should display the value 100.If I select Audi the input field should display the value 400.
I really need the help please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt at a solution before posting here. Then, when you do post, you'll post what you've tried and a ***specific*** question about the problem you are having.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, In my humble opinion, the question is well understood. The OP wants to display the value after the dash in the input field. 100 or 200 etc.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov It has nothing to do with the question being understood. We have guidelines here on what kinds of questions that should be asked here. This question doesn't meet those standards. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We expect the OP to make an attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this solution.

`element.options` and `element.selectedIndex` will do the trick. Here is the link for [details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

```js
const select = document.querySelector('#cars');
const input = document.querySelector('#name');

select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const option = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
  const value = option.text.split('-')[1];
  input.value = value;
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
    <body>
        <select name="cars" id="cars">
            <option value="volvo">Volvo-100</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab-200</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-300</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi-400</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="100">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We tend to not answer questions that don't belong here in the first place (as this one doesn't even make an attempt at a solution and doesn't ask a single specific question) as that just attracts more poor questions.  Not only that, but your post doesn't even explain what it's doing or why it works.

Comment: updated my answer! thanks. And i'll keep in mind your advice 

Comment: Your update doesn't do anything to make it clear what it's doing and a link describing the core details is more appropriate as a comment. This question just shouldn't be answered because it should be closed. We don't want to answer poor questions because it just attracts more poor questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty simply by using `change` event listener. You would also have to update the `value` attribute of each `option` to the values you specified in your question. The `event.target.value` will provide you the first selected option.

For example:

```js
const selectEl = document.querySelector('#cars');
const textInputEl = document.querySelector('#name');

selectEl.addEventListener('change', event => {
  textInputEl.value = event.target.value;
});
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="100">Volvo</option>
  <option value="200">Saab</option>
  <option value="300">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="400">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

Resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @ScottMarcus The answer is correct though, so I don't think it deserves a downvote. I think it would be more appropriate to vote to close the question for the reason you specified instead of just downvoting each answer and spamming your comment. The question will be closed if other community members agree with your judgement.

Comment: It seems OP wants to send volvo to the server and show Volvo-100 and 100 in the field

Comment: I have voted to close the question. The voting system is meant to rate the quality of an answer not just on whether it works, but on its quality. Answers that do nothing but attract more poor questions here should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

1. use addEventListener
2. Split the text if present
3. Add a 0 option otherwise you cannot select volvo from start
4. Do not name a field `name` since name is used elsewhere in the DOM and the field does not hold a name

```js
document.getElementById("cars").addEventListener("change", function() {
  const text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text
  const value = this.selectedIndex > 0 ? text.split("-")[1] : "";
  document.getElementById("carNumber").value = value;

})
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo-100</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab-200</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-300</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi-400</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="carNumber" name="carNumber">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with these two lines:

```js
const [cars, name] = ['cars', 'name'].map(document.getElementById.bind(document));

cars.addEventListener('change', ({
    target: {
      selectedOptions: {
        0: option
      }
    }
  }) => name.value = option.innerText.split('-')[1]);
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo-100</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab-200</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-300</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi-400</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

Comment: The OP wants to display the value after the dash in the input field. 100 or 200 etc.

Comment: I try to focus on code elegance to solve this kind of simple problem

Comment: Code is elegant, but FAR OVER OPs head. Also how to select volvo-100 without toggling to something else first?

Comment: I do however not see the point of this: `const [cars, name] = ['cars', 'name'].map(document.getElementById.bind(document));
`

Comment: Just a single line of code instead of two. Would also work for more queries by ID in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the solution:***

```js
function getSelectedCar(sel) {
  document.getElementById("name").value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text.split('-')[1]
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars" onChange="getSelectedCar(this);">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo-100</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab-200</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-300</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi-400</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

Comment: The OP wants to display the value after the dash in the input field. 100 or 200 etc.

Comment: Updated my answer @s.kuznetsov

Answer (score -2):

You’ve got a conflict of identifiers.

I changed id="name" with **xname** and also added a **onchange** event.

```
  <select name="cars" id="cars" onchange="xname.value=this.value;">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo-100</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab-200</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-300</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi-400</option>
    </select>
    
    
    <input type="text" id="xname" name="name" value="abc">
```

Comment: Another way is to follow the site guidelines and not use inflammatory comments. As a new user, you may just want to learn about the platform before slinging insults at those who are trying to let you know.

Comment: And (fyi) having an `id` and a `name` is not a conflict of identifiers (since `id` is the identifier and `name` is used only when form data is submitted) and does not cause a problem at all. Having them both be the same is considered a best practice so that you don't have two terms describing the same one thing.

Comment: I don't think anyone should use a browser that doesn't support HTML properly.

Comment: And, as someone who so well informed, you're using inline event attributes, which you shouldn't be doing and you are not even invoking a callback function in that attribute. So basically, you're doing the wrong thing and then stating that it won't work when the correct thing is used. Clearly, you don't have a clue about any of this.

Comment: Go ahead and tell me why this works then? https://jsfiddle.net/Lk08tgwd/